# Angular Material Sidenav doesn't cover the whole page

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

After checking examples and trying one of them for myself, I have realized that there's a blank hole that appears under the sidenav. It's probably not related with sidenav, but after you click the menu icon on the top-left most corner, (after sidenav opens) there's huge blank hole appears at the bottom of the page and I couldn't find the reason for that behaviour.

Here's the stackblitz link for that:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav

Thanks for any explanation, have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to add css to your `<mat-sidenav-container>` like in Material example :

```
.example-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
```